# How to delete and keep a local file beyond branch merges?

Tags: git, git-merge, tortoisegit

Typical work flow of using TortoiseGit:

- Master branch contains file x
- we create a new branch 'Branch_new' copied from master
- We delete (or set it to ignore) file x on master, chose to keep the file locally however and commit the change
- we switch to 'Branch_new' and merge with master, file x will now be deleted from index and(!) locally on Branch_new without any feedback or option of keeping it

This is really annoying to me because I have to manually restore it on every single one of my branches when merging with master. Is there a way to ignore the file on all of my branches and not lose it during merges?

Comment: A bit confused. 1) How can you delete the file x and at the same time still keep it locally? In another path? 2) Once a file is tracked by git, it can no longer be ignored by gitignore machanism unless you remove it from the whole history. 3) Why do you delete the file x?

Comment: 1) TortoiseGit shows this option to delete a file from index but keep it on disk, i.e. if you want to remove an accidentially tracked file which you still need. 2) Idk what exactly you mean by whole history, but in TortoiseGit ignoring tracked files will be converted into a delete and an entry in .gitignore. I'm not trying to purge it from the entire repository history, only from this point in time onwards. 3) see 1)

Comment: If you have addde it and made a commit before, I mean if `git log master -- path_of_x` can output any commit log, git will not ignore this file any longer even if you add the file into .gitignore, unless you use `git filter-branch` to remove it from all the commits, which will rewrite the history and thus is not recommanded. If you don't need it on master, just `git rm -- path_of_x` and `git commit`. Why do you always remove it from index? What's your concern?

Comment: As stated above, I guess TortoiseGit internally converts this into a delete and adds the file or extention to .gitignore afterwards. That's why this works perfectly fine for me. Concerning the last question, imagine you accidentially committed a config file that's not part of the code base and shouldn't end up in any VCS because it's user/system-specific. Once you notice, you'd like to remove it from git but still keep it in your working directory for all branches because it's still part of your configuration.

Comment: since you have already committed the file x on master, it's also on Branch_new. You could just leave it alone, and do not remove it from the index after you checkout Branch_new. If you accidentally add and commit it for the first time, before `git push` you could back it up and run `git rm -- path_of_x;git commit --amend` to rewrite the last commit, and add it to .gitignore. As long as .gitignore works, the file x will not bother you. If `git push` has been done and you don't care the published branch in the remote repo, you could update it with your new master without x by force.